# Reset Skydrive/OneDrive sync?

Tags: sync, windows-8.1, onedrive

Is there a way to have Skydrive/Onedrive completely restart the sync process and have all of the files as "online-only". I'm running Windows 8.1 Update 1.

While there is "make all files online-only" in the OneDrive metro app - it doesn't work for me. It seems that OneDrive state is corrupted on my machine, the service believes that some files are not synced when in fact they are.

I guess deleting the user account and adding it back would do the trick but I'm looking for an easier solution at this point.

Comment: Also see: [How to reset SkyDrive/OneDrive sync?](http://superuser.com/questions/741414/how-to-reset-skydrive-onedrive-sync?lq=1)