# OneDrive Sync and High Resource Usage

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, cpu-usage, onedrive

Lately the OneDrive sync on my Windows 8.1 machine has been running away with the CPU.  It doesn't noticeably affect system performance, but it's running hot enough that the fan is always on high.

(Which I suspect isn't good for it.  So most times I leave syncing in a paused state which drops things back down to normal levels.)

A few Google searches have suggested things like:

1. Turn off indexing.  Tried that, no change.
2. Trying to sync a file with strange characters in the name.  I have many files, not sure how I'd even go about trying to identify one errant file.

As far as I know everything is syncing fine.  It's always "looking for changes" and pegging the CPU though.  Any thoughts on what else might be wrong and how to address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to reset SkyDrive/OneDrive sync?](https://superuser.com/questions/741414/how-to-reset-skydrive-onedrive-sync)

As mentioned there run troubleshooter first as it might fix it or suggest where a corrupt file is. The reset can take a LONG time but is almost guaranteed to fix local issues.